# HighCharts - pass mean value from bell curve to a function

Tags: charts, highcharts, statistics, bell-curve

I am using Highcharts and  I have a histogram with bull curve behind. Everything works well, bell curve generates mean and standard deviation numbers . I would like to know if there is a way of passing the mean and standard deviation numbers that are on top of the curve to an outside function so that I can conduct another statistical operation with them.

Thanks,

Comment: Include code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required values from created chart. For example:

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
});

const bellCurveSeries = chart.series[0];
const mean = bellCurveSeries.mean;
const xData = bellCurveSeries.xData;
const yData = bellCurveSeries.yData;

console.log(mean, xData, yData);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v7prbxmo/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#series